# QGIS print layout: counting only exported pages

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts

I build an atlas layout containing an attribute table that is spanned over several pages. The attribute table of course is of various length due to the number of objects enlisted. So I set up 10 dummy pages to catch every possible number of objects occurring. The pages also have header and footer texts including the number of pages.

I managed to only export those pages where the frame isn't emtpy.

[image: Don't export page if frame is emtpy]

But the `numpages` variable in the footer is still counting every page I set up in the layout regardless of it beeing exported or not.
Here is an example of the layout exported as pdf opened in a pdf viewer:

[image: example of incorrect page number count in pdf export]

Now I'd like to modify the number of all pages in the footer that it only counts the pages that are beeing exported in the end.

Is there any way of accessing the information saying that a page is going to be included in the export or not?

Comment: I recommend using the `[% @atlas_featurenumber %] / [% @atlas_totalfeatures %]` variables like this.
IThen, the filter you use in the page exclusions, use it as a filter in the atlas

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work for my problem. I've got up to 10 pages for 1 atlas feature. The attribute table contains polygons of another layer intersecting the atlas feature. Each layout (exported as pdf) is completely independent. The pdfs all belong to seperate projects.